# UNIX Shell script: file reading issue

Tags: file, shell, unix

I have to read a file in my shell script. I was using PL/SQL's UTL_FILE to open the file. 
But I have to do a new change which will append timestamp to the file.

> e.g import.data file becomes import_20152005101200.data

Now timestamp is the time at which file arrive at the server. 
Since the file name changed I can't use the old way of file accessing. 
I came up with below solution:

> UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('path','import_${file_date}.data','r');

To achieve this I have to get filename and trim it using SUBSTR to get timestamp and pass to **file_date** variable.
However I am not able to find how to access filename in a particular path. I can use basename. But My file name keeps changing because of timestamp.

Any help/ alternate ideas are welcome.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to find the name of a file in a given location?

Comment: I got it. I used ls -1 and passed the filename to a temp file. Later I read it and get the file name.

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL isn't a good tool to solve this problem; `UTL_FILE` doesn't have any tools to list all the files in a folder.

A better solution is to define a stored procedure which uses `UTL_FILE` and pass the file name to process as an argument to the procedure. That way, you use the shell (which has many powerful commands and tools to examine folders and files) or a script language like Python to determine which file to process.

Comment: Yes. I did it using shell commands only. Using ls -1. Thank you